# What does this statement 'p = I.ptr<uchar>(i);' do?

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

Apparently, the search engine doesn't seem to be taking this symbol ' <> ' into search, Hence can anyone please explain to me what does this symbol mean as well as the statement?

For the statement, I can guess that

```
p = I.ptr<uchar>(i);
```

p happens to be pointing at I[i] address.

Thanks :)

Comment: Does OpenCV have no online documentation?

Comment: The Google query you are looking for is "C++ templates"

Comment: @iehrlich That's very helpful. Thank You

Comment: Please [read the doc](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a5a9ffc908ac90604f36a8b6a1038747d) before posting such questions. BTW, `p` points to the beginning of the `i`-th row of `I`, not to `I[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's calling a member function of the class with an argument of `i`.  For example

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Something {
public:
    template <typename T>
    T do_something(T in) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
        return in;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto something = Something{};
    // <int> not really needed here, the type can be deduced,
    // just here for demonstration purposes
    auto integer = something.do_something<int>(1);
    (void) integer;
}
```

---

Note that in order to do this in the context of a template type you would need to prefix the method call with `template` as explained in this question - [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: so ptr is a function of class I and argument passed is i? What does that <int> do in your code?

Comment: @MaNyYaCk `ptr` is a method of the class, and the argument passed is `i` yes.  the `int` in my code does the same thing as `i` in yours.  Although the `<int>` is not needed, the type can be deduced

Comment: so the <uchar> in my code is basically a typecasting?

Comment: @MaNyYaCk it's supplying a type parameter to a template method